# Socket.io Trouble with Emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to make a WebSocket server with Socket.io. When a new socket joins a room, I want to notify all the other sockets and also retrieve a list of sockets in the room for the new joiner.

socket.to(room).emit() seems to send to everyone in the room, but the documentation says socket.to().emit() should send to everyone but the sender. Is this correct?

```
namespace.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('join-lobby', (pkg) => {
        socket.join(pkg.lobbyid);
        var x = Array.from(namspace.adapter.rooms.get(pkg.lobbyid));
1.      socket.emit('joined-lobby', {players:x});
2.      socket.to(pkg.lobbyid).emit('player-join', {joiner:socket.id});
        // socket.to sends to sender as well??
    });
}
```

This is what I have on the server side. That socket should only receive the 'joined-lobby' emission (1), all others should receive the 'player-join' emission (2).

Comment: It is sending the `player-join` packet to the sender too?

Comment: Solved it, don't worry